# Create multi level scrollabe menu in Android (like Camera360 app)

Tags: android, menu, photo, scrollable

I'm building a photo effect app for android, and i want to create a menu like Camera360 app's menu (please view menu image link):

[image]
How can i create menu like this or support library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the menu at the bottom using a ScrollView that holds a row of buttons. The new menu after the click in your image looks like another Activity with the same layout. I recreated a rough version of it like so:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:scrollbarSize="0dp">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp" android:text="op1" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn2" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp" android:text="op2" />
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Tinker with the parameters and visuals and you're all set!

In order to make it 'multi-level' you can add onClickListeners that launch an acquitted activity according to your menu tree. For communication between activities, you can use [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Comment: Thanks, i will try it. 
Is there any libraries support this on Github?

Comment: @Sonzero I haven't chexked but as demostrated the implementation is extremly simple, so I doubt it